# Why Vue .sync command not working in router view?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to sync a variable between components using the `.sync` command in Vue. It works without problems when I put components in the page using the tag (for example: `<my-component></my-component>`). When I bind it in a `<router-view>`, it works only one-way. Is it normal?

When I click on the link inside the component, it does not change the value of `test` in the root Vue object. When I change it in the root object, the component inherits the value correctly.

[Click here for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/o8r9nzv5/9/)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "works only one-way"? Besides, if you check in the console, Vue actually warns you to avoid mutating a prop directly.

Comment: So can't I edit a property? In components it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the prop directly, the correcto way to update it is to emit an update. Remember `:test.sync` is a [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) to `v-bind:test` and `v-on:update:test`

On your Foo component:

```
editTest: function() {     
  this.$emit('update:test', false)  // instead of this.test = false;        
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/u7k5qpwz/

Comment: I tried, but it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/o8r9nzv5/10/

Comment: You need to write on your Foo component (child). I put a js fiddle on my answer